# gcc permanently change c standard

Tags: c, gcc, standards, c99

Is there a way of telling gcc to use the c99 standard when compiling c files as a default?
I want to avoid giving it the `-std=c99` parameter all the time.
I assume I can do this by creating an alias in the .bashrc file, but seems to be rather inelegant.

Comment: Possible duplication of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060799/c99-not-default-c-version-for-gcc

Comment: Actually, aliases in `bashrc` are an elegant (and standard) solution for many "customization" problems of this sort, though I wouldn't recommend masking the name `gcc`--you should name your alias something else. (E.g. `ll` is commonly aliased to `ls -lA`.)

Answer (score 6):

You may call `c99` instead of `gcc` (wrapper for gcc, if it's available on your system) or try to modify your gcc spec file. More information here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Spec-Files.html

Comment: c99 is effectively a prerequisite on all POSIX platforms. But beware, that it mustn't necessarily point to the same version of gcc. Namely on OS X, c99 is a completely obsolete version of gcc.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an unexpected answer. Use a Makefile!

Pros:

- Simply type `make` to build
- All options are automatically handled in the build process.
  While you're at it, go ahead and enable all warnings, as is good to do. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574200/gcc-is-using-werror-and-pedantic-considered-good-practice).
- Easy to scale up to multiple source files
- Can handle multi-step builds involving different tools

Cons:

- Another tool to learn, another thing to get wrong.

Consider this source:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello!\n");
    int x = 4;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

You could make a Makefile like this:
(Disclaimer, I don't actually know how to write them)

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -pedantic -std=c99
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

.PHONY: clean

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(EXECUTABLE)
```

And it builds for me.

Likewise, if you remove the `-std=c99`, it shouldn't be valid C89 code, and indeed, typing `make` brings up the build error.

Comment: "Another tool to learn, another thing to get wrong....Disclaimer, I don't actually know how to write them" No offense, but I think you've severely undermined your own answer with those statements. Build systems are extremely important for non-trivial projects, but (1) raw Make is (IMO) a pretty terrible choice of build systems, and (2) build systems aren't really necessary or helpful for single-file "sandbox"-style compilation.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that just defining `CFLAGS` (and doing nothing else in the Makefile) is an okay solution here; `make` will auto-generate targets using the default args (I did not realize this). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32485029/1858225

Answer (score 1):

Custom compilation suggests you have at a working knowledge of compilers, standards, and basic flags / options. For that reason, I suggest you set shell variables in your `.bashrc`, `.tcshrc`, etc., and use them on the command line.

Since the choice of dialect can have an effect on linking: `CC="gcc -std=c99"`, lets you invoke separate compilation commands using `$CC -c -O2 ... foo.c`, and is also picked up as the default for `configure` scripts, etc. Of course, you can always override a `configure` script with `CC="gcc -std=c90"` or `CC="clang"`. The same applies to a preferred `CFLAGS` value, e.g.,

`CFLAGS="-pipe -W -Wall -O2 -march=core2"`

Allows for `$CC $CFLAGS -c foo.c` commands, and both environment variables are used by default with configure scripts, unless you explicitly override them. I think this is more useful than aliases. But perhaps I've just grown used to my own setup:)

Comment: I've fixed a couple of your variable assignments, which needed quotes to be handled properly in Bash (and probably most or all other standard shells). I think an alias would be a good solution when used *in conjunction with* your suggestion of variable assignments: `alias cc="$CC $CFLAGS"`.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the proposed solutions are, in my opinion, *almost* what you want, but neither quite gets there.

## Makefile solution

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32485029/1858225), by defining variables in your `Makefile` but *not* defining targets, you can use the `make` command like a customized pass-through to GCC. So if you create a `Makefile` in your "sandbox" directory (or wherever you're compiling outside of a real build system) and define the `C*FLAGS` vars, you'll essentially get what you want. An example Makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c99
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -std=c++14
```

Now, `make foo` will turn `foo.c` into an executable called `foo`.

If you want to do this trick in multiple directories, put your makefile in a known location--say, `~/sandbox`--and create the following alias (or something like it) in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias usestdmake="ln -s ~/sandbox/Makefile"
```

Then you can quickly compile a single file anywhere on your machine:

```
usestdmake
make foo
```

This has the added advantage of giving the output executable an appropriate name (`foo` in this case). It has the disadvantage of disabling tab-completion for your compile command (`make fo<tab>` does nothing, at least on my system).

## Pure `bashrc` solution

The `CC`/`CFLAGS` variables mentioned in Brett Hale's answer are fairly standard, so it might be a good idea to define them in your `bashrc`. You can then use these variables inside of aliases.

In your `.bashrc`:

```
CFLAGS="-Wall -std=c99"
CC=gcc
# Use single-ticks to ensure that the variables are evaluated when the alias is evaluated.
alias mycc='$CC $CFLAGS'
```

On the command line:

```
cc foo.c    # Compile with default CFLAGS
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -O2" cc foo.c    # Compile with modified CFLAGS
```