# Sorting program stops working without any error

Tags: c, sorting

I typed the following code to sort the components of an int array. It does not show any error but does stops working abruptly. The error is generally after entering 7-8 inputs which shows that program.exe has stopped working. Does it has anything related to the code ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n,a[n],i,j,temp;
    printf("Enter number of inputs.\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter inputs\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]<a[j])
            {
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Numbers in descending order are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `prog.cc:6:12: warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]
prog.cc:6:13: warning: variable 'n' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]`

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The first thing you should do is, fix your program and always listen to your compiler warnings (and notes)! [Just enable them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574200/gcc-is-using-werror-and-pedantic-considered-good-practice).
Next thing, [try to debug simple programs yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems), it is not that hard and will save you hours of asking ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
int n, a[n], i, j, temp;
```

Declarations are done sequentially. If you write this in a slighly more readably (but equivalent form) you'd have this:

```
int n;
int a[n];    // here the variable n has not yet been initialized
             // it contains an indeterminate value, and therefore the a array
             // will have an indeterminate size and the program will have
             // so called "undefined behaviour " (google that)
int i;
...
```

You should write the beginning of your program like this:

```
int main()
{
    int n,i,j,temp;
    printf("Enter number of inputs.\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];                  // now n has a determinate value
    printf("Enter inputs\n");
```

Disclaimer: no error checking is done for brevity.

Always compile with warnings enabled and listen to them. Many of them are actually errors. Especially the warning *variable 'somevar' is uninitialized when used here* is always an error.