# C - pass an input and an output text file through command line to my program

Tags: c, file-handling

I need to pass two files through my program in command line form

```
./your_executable inputfile.txt outputfile.txt
```

In my example, I'm using

```
gcc coursework.c CircleCode.txt CircleCode_tmp.txt
```

Therefore the second file doesn't exist and is opened in the program.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{
    FILE *orginalFile = fopen(*argv[1], "r");
    FILE *newFile = fopen(*argv[2], "w");

    if (orginalFile == NULL || newFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

The error in *Clang*:

```
error: no such file or directory: 'CircleCode_tmp.txt'
```

Comment: Your declaraction of parameter `argv` is incorrect.  You may use `char **argv`, or you may use `char *argv[]`; these are equivalent.  On the other hand, your `char **argv[]` means something different, and it will not match the actual argument.  Once you correct the declaration, correct also the uses, which each should have one fewer level of indirection.

Comment: You should also check `if (argc < 3) { fputs ("error: insufficient input.\n", stderr); return 1; }` prior to using `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`. If no arguments are passed, `argv[1]` will be `NULL` and `argv[2]` an indeterminate address.

Comment: Er... you're passing those filenames to your **compiler**. You want them as command line arguments to the program itself when you run it.

Comment: You need to compile and run as two different steps. Compile with **gcc -Wall coursework.c -o coursework**  Run with **./coursework CircleCode.txt CircleCode_tmp.txt** Of course, you also need to fix the problems mentioned in the other comments.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of your `main()` is not right.

It could change it to

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

since `argv` is to point to an array of strings.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2108192/5375464).

---

Since you need the input and output files for your program to work, you should check if the required number of arguments are received or not.

`argc` will have the number of arguments. Since the name of the command used to run the program itself is counted as an argument, along with the two files, the program needs at least 3 arguments.

So you may do something like

```
if(argc<3)
{                                                                        
   perror("Not enough arguments.");                                       
   return 1;                                                              
}
```

---

Also, with

```
gcc coursework.c CircleCode.txt CircleCode_tmp.txt
```

you are asking the compiler to compile your input and output text files as well which is probably not what you want.

Instead, you could do

```
gcc -Wall coursework.c -o your_executable
```

to compile the program and then run it like

```
./your_executable CircleCode.txt CircleCode_tmp.txt
```

The `-Wall` option of `gcc` is used to enable some warnings which may better help you spot and correct errors.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574200/gcc-is-using-werror-and-pedantic-considered-good-practice) discussion as well.

Answer (score 0):

argv type is char**, not need []

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* orginalFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE* newFile = fopen(argv[2], "w");

    if (orginalFile == NULL || newFile == NULL) {
      printf("Cannot open file");
      exit(0);
    }
}
```